# Can bones in IK chains be also moved independently?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have the following IK chain:

[image]

Bone 3 is the IK bone and 4 is the IK target. Clearly, when 4 is moved the entire chain follows it. Which leads to the problem that it is impossible to move the bones that are subordinate to 4 independently with 4 following them.

I would like to rotate Bone 3 with 4 following the rotation. Is it possible to have an IK bone in control of a chain and still be able to transform the subordinate bones independently with the control bone following the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, sure.  You just add another bone:

[image]

In your particular case, you would:

1. Duplicate bone 3 and delete any constraints from this duplicate.
2. Parent this duplicate to bone 3.
3. Disable deform on bone 3, and rename any vertex groups on the mesh to follow the duplicate instead ("3.001" likely.)

That way, bone 3 still takes place in the IK chain, and you have a deforming bone that defaults to the orientation of 3, but is still independently manipulable.

Should be said, even though you *can* do that, it doesn't mean you *should* do that.  How most people would approach the situation in your picture is to make 2 the IK bone, move the rest pose of 4 to the rest pose tail of 2, decrement the chain length by 1, and then give 3 a world->world copy rotation constraint targeting 4.  (An alternative here is to enable rotation on the IK constraint, but that's less reliable-- the IK solver doesn't do well with rotation enabled.)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to rotate those supporting joints, the IK would suddenly not be in the right spot. Use poles to tell the knee where to point, as the leg is currently backwards which is what I assume you're trying to fix

Comment: No, the knee is pointing in the right direction. What I'm trying to do is rotate Bone 3 backwards, so that looks like the animal has his legs folded and is seating down.

Comment: @ConnyDago moving bone 3 isnt possible since it relies on bone 4 to determine its rotation. moving the IK handle down to where the foot needs to be will fix it.